# How to use EditorForModel and DataAnnotations for complex types in a wrapping ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, viewmodel, data-annotations, editorformodel

I have a ViewModel wrapping two complex types:

```
public class EditProductViewModel
{
    public ProductData ProductData { get; set; }
    public FridgeContent FridgeContent { get; set; }
}
```

and this view:

```
@model EditProductViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ProductData", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.EditorForModel()
   [...]
}
```

ProductData and FridgeContent contain POCO properties with DataAnnotations like this:

```
public class FridgeContentMetadata : DatabaseEntityMetadataBase
{
    [Required]
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    public int ProductDataId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UIHint("StringReadOnly")]
    public int ScaleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [UIHint("StringReadOnly")]
    [Range(0.01, float.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "The weight of a product must be positive.")]
    public float Weight { get; set; }

    [...]
}
```

I want to edit both ProductData and FridgeContent in the EditProductView using the appropriate data annotations from those classes and the EditorForModel() method (I don't want to generate the templates myself). I therefore created the templates ProductData.cshtml and FridgeContent.cshtml in /Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/:

```
@model FridgeContent 
@Html.EditorForModel()
```

Unfortunately, the view for EditProductViewModel is empty (no errors raised). If I use EditorForModel for either FridgeContent or ProductData alone, it's working fine. I also tried adding [UIHInt("..")] annotations to EditProductViewModel but that doesn't make a difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

```
@model EditProductViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "ProductData", FormMethod.Post))
{
   @Html.EditorFor(o=> o.ProductData )

   @Html.EditorFor(o=> o.FridgeContent )
}
```

or create an edit template for you ViewModel containing these two lines

```
   @Html.EditorFor(o=> o.ProductData )
   @Html.EditorFor(o=> o.FridgeContent )
```

**UPADTE:**

Oh got it finally because the rendering engine will not go more that one step in object hierarchy, you can find it in asp.net mvc code also.

Check the MVC 3.0 Source Code [Here](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/releases/view/58781):

There is a file named `DefaultEditorTemplates.cs` which contains this method:

```
internal static string ObjectTemplate(HtmlHelper html, TemplateHelpers.TemplateHelperDelegate templateHelper) {
    ViewDataDictionary viewData = html.ViewContext.ViewData;
    TemplateInfo templateInfo = viewData.TemplateInfo;
    ModelMetadata modelMetadata = viewData.ModelMetadata;
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    if (templateInfo.TemplateDepth > 1) {    // DDB #224751
        return modelMetadata.Model == null ? modelMetadata.NullDisplayText : modelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText;
    }

    foreach (ModelMetadata propertyMetadata in modelMetadata.Properties.Where(pm => ShouldShow(pm, templateInfo))) {
        if (!propertyMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml) {
            string label = LabelExtensions.LabelHelper(html, propertyMetadata, propertyMetadata.PropertyName).ToHtmlString();
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(label)) {
                builder.AppendFormat(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<div class=\"editor-label\">{0}</div>\r\n", label);
            }

            builder.Append("<div class=\"editor-field\">");
        }

        builder.Append(templateHelper(html, propertyMetadata, propertyMetadata.PropertyName, null /* templateName */, DataBoundControlMode.Edit, null /* additionalViewData */));

        if (!propertyMetadata.HideSurroundingHtml) {
            builder.Append(" ");
            builder.Append(html.ValidationMessage(propertyMetadata.PropertyName));
            builder.Append("</div>\r\n");
        }
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

which clearly states that if the `TemplateDepth > 1` just render a simple text.

Comment: If I just put a string in the EditorTemplate for ProductData or FridgeContent, it works but using EditorForModel() doesn't.

Comment: If you want to use the EditorForModel you must create an edit template, I've add that part to answer.

Comment: No, I mean I can't use EditorForModel() in the EditorTemplate for ProductData or FridgeContent. I added your code to the EditProductViewModel view and this is working but only if the called EditorTemplates contain simple strings instead of EditorForModel().

Comment: Because you have a single `Model` property behind a view which is `EditProductViewModel`

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it. Obviously, specifying an EditorTemplate for the EditProductViewModel that should show the EditorTemplates for ProductData and FridgeContent works: If I just put the string "ProductData Template" in the ProductData EditorTemplate and "FridgeContent Template" in the one for FridgeContent, both strings are displayed. But why can't I write EditorForModel() instead of "ProductData Template" in it although this specific EditorTemplate is typed to @model ProductData?

Comment: Also weird: If I put @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScaleId) in the EditorTemplate for FridgeContent, I get the following exception: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Int', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.String'.

Comment: That's because this annotation `[UIHint("StringReadOnly")]` on top of `ScaleId` property

Comment: And for generating the Editor and Display templates for every object you can define an object template named Object.cshtml and write a code to spit out the correct html for every object, take a look at this for starting point: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Comment: I couldn't make it work, even with the object template and ended up putting @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ScaleId) and so on into the EditorTemplate for FridgeContent and ProductData. While this adds an unnecessary layer of maintainance, I think I can still live with this workaround. Thanks for your help, especially for the one about the UIHint annotation!

Comment: Oh got it finally because the rendering engine will not go more that one step in object hierarchy, you can find it in asp.net mvc code also.

Answer (score 0):

As the above answer shows, this problem seems related to the framework limiting the depth of nesting it will consider.

One way to work around the problem is to use your own editor template. Create the partial view, `Object.cshtml`, in `Views/Shared/EditorTemplates`. Here's an example template taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/hazzik/1200683):

```
@{
    Func<ModelMetadata, bool> ShouldShow = metadata =>
        metadata.ShowForEdit && !ViewData.TemplateInfo.Visited(metadata);
}
@if (ViewData.TemplateInfo.TemplateDepth > 5) {
    if (Model == null) { 
        @ViewData.ModelMetadata.NullDisplayText 
    } else { 
        @ViewData.ModelMetadata.SimpleDisplayText 
    } 
} else {     
    foreach (var prop in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties.Where(ShouldShow)) { 
        if (prop.HideSurroundingHtml) { 
            @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName) 
        } else { 
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Html.Label(prop.PropertyName).ToHtmlString())==false) { 
                <div class="editor-label">
                    @Html.Label(prop.PropertyName) 
                </div>
            } 
            <div class="editor-field">
                @Html.Editor(prop.PropertyName)  
                @Html.ValidationMessage(prop.PropertyName) 
            </div>
        } 
    } 
}
```

In the above example, you can set the maximum nesting depth by changing the `5` constant.